# What are the other pins grouped witht he RUN pin on a raspberry pi (zero)?

Tags: gpio, pi-zero

On my raspberry pi zero, there is a group of four pins next to the gpio header, at the end with the camera connector.  One of these is the `RUN` pin. What are the other three?